# MDX: Query Optimization

Tags: ssas, mdx

For displaying the result set, it takes 2 minutes. Is there any way to optimise the query?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[TestMeasure] AS
  ( 
    [Measures].[EnrollPatientCnt] 
  + [Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt] 
  + [Measures].[ProgramAssessmentPatientCnt] 
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[TotalCount] AS
  Count( 
    NonEmpty(
     ( 
       { [DimAssessment].[AssessmentText].[AssessmentText] },
       { [DimAssessment].[QuestionText].[QuestionText] },
       { [DimAssessment].[AnswerText].[AnswerText] } 
     )
    ,{ 
       [Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt]
     , [Measures].[TestMeasure] 
     }
  ) )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY [Measures].[TotalCount] ON COLUMNS
FROM [NavigateCube]
WHERE 
  (
    {
      ( 
       { 
         [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationName].&[1034]&[TC Tammy Brown Care Team] 
       } 
      )
    } 
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

How does this query perform?

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[TestMeasure] AS
  IIf(
   Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[EnrollPatientCnt]))
   or Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt]))
   or Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[ProgramAssessmentPatientCnt]))
   ,1
   ,Null
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[TotalCount] AS
  Sum (
    ( { [DimAssessment].[AssessmentText].[AssessmentText] },
    { [DimAssessment].[QuestionText].[QuestionText] },
    { [DimAssessment].[AnswerText].[AnswerText] } ),
    [Measures].[TestMeasure]
  )
SELECT NON EMPTY [Measures].[TotalCount] ON COLUMNS
FROM [NavigateCube]
WHERE (
{
  ( { [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationName].&[1034]&[TC Tammy Brown Care Team] } )
} )
```

It's not identical, but it's a similar concept to what Mosha blogged about [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20170614093509/http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/11/22/optimizing-count-filter-expressions-in-mdx.aspx).

Comment: Greg - `mdx` tag has been proposed for documentation - can you add your vote please as we need several votes to create the documentation for this tag: stackoverflow.com/documentation/mdx

Comment: @greg - unsurprisingly, as MS were probably annoyed at its continual string of hits!, the link you've included does not work anymore

Comment: @whytheq thanks for the heads up. Fixed. Mosha isn't at Microsoft anymore.

Comment: @GregGalloway excellent change of hyperlink - I never thought about that. Can you also fix my MDXStudio so it works again?!! .... seems like the latest windows update has killed it (like you said he doesn't work there anymore so they are quite in their rights to break perfectly functional stuff and replace it with stuff that does the same thing! [tabular])

Answer (score 0):

Basically the same approach as Greg/Mosha:

```
WITH 
MEMBER [Measures].[TestMeasure] AS
    [Measures].[EnrollPatientCnt] 
  + [Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt] 
  + [Measures].[ProgramAssessmentPatientCnt] 
MEMBER [Measures].[MeasureIsEmpty] AS
  IIF(
      NOT ISEMPTY([Measures].[TestMeasure])
   OR NOT ISEMPTY([Measures].[AssessmentPatientCnt])
   ,1
   ,NULL
  )
MEMBER [Measures].[TotalCount] AS
  SUM(
     [DimAssessment].[AssessmentText].[AssessmentText]
    *[DimAssessment].[QuestionText].[QuestionText]
    *[DimAssessment].[AnswerText].[AnswerText]
    ,[Measures].[MeasureIsEmpty]
  )
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY [Measures].[TotalCount] ON 0
FROM [NavigateCube]
WHERE [DimManagedPopulation].[ManagedPopulationName].&[1034]&[TC Tammy Brown Care Team];
```

Comment: Hi @whytheq, the above query helps a lot to me. thank u

Comment: glad this was some sort of help